# Как получить "ИТОГО:" ?

Tags: javascript

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите пожалуйста с решением проблемы. Суть проблемы в том, чтобы вывести "ИТОГО:" по каждому столбцу. [Здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/mnVfJ/) накидал пример самой таблицы. Чтобы было понятнее эта таблица расчета кредита (кредитный калькулятор), значение сделал рандомные, поскольку в каждой строке идет расчет и здесь его описывать не логично будет. Можно было бы создать массив и наполнять его походу, но сложность в том, что каждое значение формируется расчетом, а в каждом поле расчет разный, и не получается просто весь этот расчет занести в переменную и потом этими переменными наполнять сам массив. Понятно, что вопрос относится к разряду "сделайте за меня", не прошу решения готового, хотябы алгоритм.

***Ну или вот сама таблица:***

```
Номер п.п       Показание 1 Показание 2 Показание 3

   1                93          45         292  
   2                56         274         221 
   3               108          12         148
   4               102         250         129
   5                92         120         159  
Итого :             X           X           X
```

***Генерируется с помощью обычного JavaScript:***

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var html = '<table width="100%" border="0"><tr><td align=center><b>Номер п.п</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 1</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 2</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 3</b></td>';

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

        html+='</tr><tr><td colspan=6 ><hr></td></tr>';

        function getRandom(){
            return Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
        }

        html += '<tr>'; 
        html += '<td align=center>' + i + '</td>';
        html += '<td align=center>' + getRandom() + '</td>';
        html += '<td align=center>' + getRandom() + '</td>';
        html += '<td align=center>' + getRandom() + '</td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        html += '<tr><td colspan=4><hr></td></tr>';
        }

    html += '<tr><td align=right><b>Итого :</b></td><td align=center><b>X</b></td><td align=center><b>X</b></td><td align=center><b>X</b></td>';
    html += '</table>';

    document.write(html);

</script>
```

Comment: не совсем понятна фраза "не получается просто весь этот расчет занести в переменную". То есть значение вы все таки получаете, если выводите, но в массив его записать не можете. Так?

Comment: ну примерно так! :)

Comment: Коллеги, спасибо за участие! Всем по-пальцу вверху!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы генерируете значения только для примера, а в реальной задаче должны подсчитывать уже определенные значения в колонках, то тогда, думаю, что [этот вариант вам может пригодиться](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zQKjv/2/).

Comment: я почему-то непонимаю подхода сначала забить данные в таблицу, а потом парсить эту таблицу, чтобы достать данные

Comment: @Spectre, вопрос не ко мне, т.к. ТС не уточнил того, откуда и как берутся данные. Я даже не исключаю того, что задачу можно решить еще на стадии получения данных из БД, не прибегая к JS.

Comment: А я бы еще придрался к использованию jQuery. Код автора без использования фреймворков, значит и решение нужно предоставлять в аналогичном виде...)

Comment: Данные не из БД берутся, а с клиентской формы, и согласно данных указанных в форме идет генерация расчета ежемесячных платежей в табличной форме, все делается на клиенте!

Comment: @Равнодушный блин! ты такой назойливый мух, ни один вопрос не остался не прокоменчен от тебя :) НУ это ладно критика тоже помогает, но во-первых, я же написал НА ЧИСТОМ JAVASCRIPT

Comment: @Deonis работает! Спасибо! Фанат закрученных комбинаций :)

Comment: @archi_sova, я же не тебя критикую, а этот ответ. Надо же было что-то добавить в поддержку решения @Spectre. ;)

Comment: @Равнодушный, ааа ну понятно тогда )

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, проще всего сделать следующим образом:

```
var data = []; 
for(var i=5;i--;){
    var arr = [];
    for(var j=3;j--;){
        arr.push(getRandom());
    }
    data.push(arr);
}  
// заполнили массив, теперь добавим в этот массив значение ИТОГО:
var count = [];
for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
    count.push(data.reduce(function(acc, el){
        return acc+el[i];
    }, 0));
}
data.push(count)
```

получаем в data нечто вроди такой матрицы:

```
206, 145, 293
32,  85,  88
80,  269, 274
68,  295, 109
47,  190, 111

433, 984, 875 // ИТОГО
```

которую очень легко рендерить

Comment: ну тоже как вариант :) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

По-моему, проще всего сделать следующим образом: сначала создаёте массив из n элементов, где n это количество столбцов с показаниями (в данном случае, 3). Внутри цикла имеете примерно следующий код:

```
html+='</tr><tr><td colspan=6 ><hr></td></tr>';

function getRandom(){
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
}

html += '<tr>'; 
html += '<td align=center>' + i + '</td>';
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  var result = getRandom();
  sums[i] += result;
  html += '<td align=center>' + result + '</td>';
}
html += '</tr>';

html += '<tr><td colspan=4><hr></td></tr>';
```

Естественно, где-то до начала цикла будет задекларирован массив из 3-х элементов, каждый из них имеющий значение, равное 0

Comment: немного не подойдет по мой случай, поскольку функцию getRandom() я просто взял для примера, у меня ведь подсчет идет и сразу создается поле для таблицы, потом снова подсчет и снова генерим поле и так до тех пор пока не выведем всю таблицу, получается, что считать приходится уже в конце всей отрисованой таблицы, но за ответ спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Народ, если кому то интересно, сам еще нашел [решение](http://jsfiddle.net/mnVfJ/1/) куда более простое :)

```
var html = '<table width="100%" border="0"><tr><td align=center><b>Номер п.п</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 1</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 2</b></td><td align=center><b>Показание 3</b></td>';

var res1 = 0;
var res2 = 0;
var res3 = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++){

    html+='</tr><tr><td colspan=6 ><hr></td></tr>';

    function getRandom(){
          return Math.floor((Math.random()*300)+1);
    }

    var t1 = getRandom();
    var t2 = getRandom();
    var t3 = getRandom();

    html += '<tr>';    
    html += '<td align=center>' + i + '</td>';
    html += '<td align=center>' + t1 + '</td>';
    html += '<td align=center>' + t2 + '</td>';
    html += '<td align=center>' + t3 + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';

    html += '<tr><td colspan=4><hr></td></tr>';

    res1 = res1 + t1;
    res2 = res2 + t2;
    res3 = res3 + t3;   
}

html += '<tr><td align=right><b>Итого :</b></td><td align=center><b>'+res1+'</b></td><td align=center><b>'+res2+'</b></td><td align=center><b>'+res3+'</b></td>';
html += '</table>';

document.write(html);​
```

Comment: у вас уже ошибка в разметке. первый `<hr>` в ячейке с `colspan=6` а второй с `colspan=4`. это из-за того, что вы смешиваете разметку с данными. То, что у вас такой небольшой кусок кода еще не повод делать "как попало и чтоб сработало". Прислушайтесь к другим отвечающим и сделайте сначала расчет, потом выводите таблицу по рассчитанным данным.  
ЗЫ про `document.write` вообще молчу.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Юрий вам сюда, здесь все работает http://jsfiddle.net/mnVfJ/1/, как мне надо так и реализовал, ВЕДЬ ВЕРНО! У МЕНЯ СРАЗУ РАСЧЕТ ДЕЛАЕТСЯ и ГЕНЕРИРУЕТСЯ ТАБЛИЦА! я прислушался к советам отвечающих, в том числе и к вашему, но вы как программист, должны знать что любое решение проблемы считается решением :) это и есть доказательство того, что люди разные, ищут именно те решения которые больше всего подходят под их решение! Я ЖЕ ВЕДЬ ДАЖЕ НАПИСАЛ "ЕСЛИ КОМУ-ТО ИНТЕРЕСНО!" и не более... :)

Comment: [индусы](http://lurkmore.to/Индусский_код) и [китайцы](http://lurkmore.to/Китайский_код#K.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B9.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B9_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4) тоже считают, что главное решение и не важно как. а еще лучше побольше бессмысленного, тяжело поддерживаемого кода.

Comment: ну где тут тяжелый :) ? три ссаных строчки, а такой дебат Ахаха! ))